# Adding data to SQL database with C# with no result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I try to add data from a form to one of my SQL Server database table. I was reading all the materials on stack but it seems I am doing something wrong I can't see.

Simple code to add data, no luck

Web form

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeBehind="Reports.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="WAPReview.Reports" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Name" />
<asp:TextBox CssClass="textbox" ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<p>
<asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Save Data" />
</p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WAPReview
{
    public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            string sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tstTable (Name) VALUES (@Name)";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, conn))
            {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
                    conn.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`web.config` for connection

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WAPReview.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Any exception? Looks something suspectable in the ConnectionString!

Comment: *I was reading all the materials on stack* <-- Where?

Comment: Error. System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.'
My friend google gave me a lot of links, including stackoverflow

Comment: Are you  reading data from mdf file?

Comment: Worth reading:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

Comment: Also worth using entity framework (as per that article)

Comment: In your `connectionString` as posted, `Data Source=LocalDB)` is missing the opening parentheses.  If this is the way it is specified in your `web.config` and not just a paste-typo, please try it with the opening parenthesis: `Data Source=(LocalDB)`

Comment: Just a typo David, the original file has both parenthesis

Comment: And it's also worth considering mvc (as per that article) rather than ancient webforms. If you're learning you should learn something modern, not something that's approaching end of life (all ms focus is on net core now, webforms is .net standard and ms announced already that .net 4.8 will be the last). Webforms is gonna be supported for a while but I wouldn't start learning it in earnest now unless you need it for a legacy support role

Comment: I just want to learn how to develop a simple web based database application with Visual Studio and .net come first on my sight

Comment: Final point, on your problem.. when you say the database isn't updating, if there's no error MAKE ABSOLUTELY SURE you're looking in the correct db. The one in your dev directory might not be the one the app is updating. Search your entire hard disk for wapreview.mdf and look in all of them :)

Comment: @ Prashant. I have several dropdown list binded to other tables in the database and I can access the info

Comment: Learning mvc and ef will probably make things a lot more simple in the end than doing webforms and "sql in a click handler".. it's the concepts of "data lives here", "it is rendered by that" and "it is manipulated by that" that are most important for getting on in the modern app world and a webforms+sql route blurs those lines a bit

Comment: If you are already successfully reading info out of the db, just try using your query tool (SSMS?) to change one of those values loaded into your combo box and see if the app shows the new value. If it doesn't, you're looking in the wrong db

Comment: I only have one database named wapreview.mdf on my hard drive. I can add data to database using query in server explorer menu but not with C#

Comment: This may help  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f21c0728-935d-492a-baaf-ff2704e3683b/attachdbfilename-option-in-connection-string?forum=sqldataaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not generate onclick event of button properly replace button code by below

```
<asp:Button ID="Button" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server" Text="Save Data" />
```

and check it using breakpoint on the click event if code is executing or not.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'reports_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button_Click' and no extension method 'Button_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'reports_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: which vs version are you using?

Comment: It is working now, I forgot to revert to initial coding in the page to test your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

pls check with

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].tostring();
```

also add parathasis to webconfig connection string

```
 <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\WAPReview.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```